# Using JSF1.2, how to raise a 404 error from the backing bean?

Tags: java, http, jsf, jsf-1.2

I saw that `ExternalContext` in JSF 2.0 has a method setResponseStatus, how can I do that using JSF 1.2?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSF 1.x, you need to get the [`HttpServletResponse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) by [`ExternalContext#getResponse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getResponse%28%29) and then invoke [`setStatus()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus%28int%29) on it. This is also basically what the new JSF 2.0 method is doing under the covers.

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks! And is it safe to cast the return of `getResponse()`  to an `HttpServletResponse`? Why the need to cast?

Comment: Yes it is safe if you run JSF on top of a JSP/Servlet webapp. JSF can however also be used on top of a Portlet webapp, the cast would then fail. See also the javadoc of `ExternalContext`, it mentions differences for servlets and portlets in behaviour of the existing delegate methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html